# Linked List Implementation by Structure In C#()

Tags: c#, linked-list

I am implementing Linked List in C# so I use Two Approaches

***First Approach***

```
 unsafe public struct Node
        {
            public int info;
            public Node* link;
        }
```

Here Is Add Node Method

```
public void AddNode( int  a)
        {
            Node temp = new Node();
            temp.info = a;
               if (Head == null)
               {
                  Head = Current = &temp;        
               }
            else
            {
                    (*Current).link = &temp;  
                     Current = &temp; 
                }                                         
            }
```

When I run This Code It does not save memory means It create an instance of   `Node temp = new Node();`Structure as long as it is inside AddNode Its memory is save but when I print It outside this method using **Head**  its give me `NullRefrenceException`

***Second Approach***

By Using Class And Objects

```
    public class Node
        {
            public int info;
            public Node link;
        }
        class Linked_list
        {
           public Node Head;
           public Node Current;



            public void insert_element_linkedlist( int  a)
            {
                Node temp = new Node();
                temp.info = a;
                   if (Head == null)
                   {
                      Head = Current = temp;        
                   }
                else
                {
                        Current.link = temp;  
                         Current = temp; 
                    }                                         
                } 
}
```

The Second method is working perfectly means Every instance of temp node  `Node temp = new Node();` is save in memory .

**Question :** 
Why It does not save structure instance ?

Sorry For My Sub Standard English.

Comment: Is this simply an exercise to learn the language, or could you use the [LinkedList class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?  Also, in C# using pointers is something you should only do in very weird circumstances; I don't think a linked list implementation requires it.

Comment: It is an Exercize of Data Structure

Comment: Why it saves an instance of a class but Does not save a structure instance
What's This

Comment: I mentioned above that  I am Implementing LinkedList not using Default LinkedList class

Comment: I believe the issue here is that you are using mutable structs, which don't behave the same way that classes do when you pass values around while mutating them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure instance, being a [value type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx), gets created on the stack, so when `AddNode` returns it is cleaned up and you are left with pointers to a random place in memory.  Simply creating a pointer to a variable is not enough to keep it alive.

Comment: Yes Nice means structure is just like all other data types like `int float`

Comment: Objects are of [reference type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx).  For a struct, the data are actually stored on the stack; for an object, only the *reference* to the data is stored on the stack; the data are allocated on the heap.  Objects don't go away until they are "unreachable" (no outstanding references to them from live objects or global variables), at which point they become eligible for garbage collection.  Structs go away when the stack frame in which their data are stored goes away.

Comment: I should add that the above is probably only "approximately" correct; I may be using some wrong terminology, but that's the gist.  Also, structs are not necessarily stored on the stack, as an object can contain a struct, which would then be part of the object's data on the heap.  But their data are always stored "inline" rather than as a separate chunk of data pointed at by a reference.